# Swedish cashless economy for tourism

Tags: payment-cards, sweden, payment

As a visitor to Sweden, what are my options for paying for things?
Should I buy some kind of pre-paid card and load it?
Will merchants accept a MasterCard from Ireland with microchip/rfid?

Comment: Is there a reason you'd think they'd not accept your card? Sweden is a rich, 1st world country; it's not exactly a deep iungle remote backwater...

Comment: Cash still works in Sweden.

Comment: They took an old unchipped American credit card. Other than annoying fees by your Irish bank, there will not be an issue.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: I assume they'll take a Master Card everywhere where Master card is accepted (that's what they say on the ad). But I wonder about other means of payment that would make payment faster. What do they use there? How do you pay for a coffee?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for not simply using money?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo: http://www.bbc.com/news/business-41095004

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo More and more sellers do not accept cash any more. Physical money is a hassle and a security risk.

Comment: @QuoraFeans You pay for coffee with a card. With RFID card machines becoming more prevalent, card is fastest. POS may also forgo the use of a PIN if the amount is small enough, for expediency.

Comment: @Roddy Japan is a first world country, but doesn’t accept credit card an awful lot.

Comment: @TomasBy From a recent visit to Stockholm, lots of places (hotels, coffee shops etc) *refused* to take cash and only took cards! Big signs on the doors saying "this is a cashless premises" or similar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I visited Sweden half a year ago, and I was able to pay everywhere (from the smallest coffee shop to fancy restaurants) by just tapping my Dutch ATM card on the POS of the merchant. Dutch ATM cards are Maestro cards, and are happily accepted in Sweden.

Answer (score 9):

Sweden is amongst the most [cashless countries](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/which-are-the-world-s-most-cashless-countries.html) in the world, but cash is still widely accepted to the degree that coffee-shops or city-buses not excepting cash are exceptions.

Very few shops don't accept visa and master card; and most places have touch-less cart-terminals as well as chip and magnet card-readers.

Yet, many Swedes, like me, *never* use cash, and don't readily recognise the recently redesigned Swedish coins. Where cards are not used, amongst street-vendors and between friends, many Swedes instead use [Swish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swish_(payment)) rather than cash. Swish is a national peer-to-peer payment system tied to bank-accounts and using phone-numbers as identifiers for instant money-transfers approved by Swedish digital ID:s on smart-phones.
As a short term visitor, however, it will be difficult to get Swish, as it requires A Swedish bank account a Swedish digital ID and national ID-number. To go Dutch on a bill, buy an apple or a hot-dog from a street-vendor or to give money to beggars and street-musicians, you should consider cash which you can get readily from ATM:s.

The currency in Sweden is the crown (SEK), though some shops, like Systembolaget (the alcohol retail store) accepts other Scandinavian currencies and Euros.

The Banks of Sweden is currently [investigating the issuance of non-physical money](https://www.riksbank.se/en-gb/financial-stability/the-financial-system/payments/does-sweden-need-an-e-krona/) in compliance with the trends towards a cash-less economy.

Contactless payments are available almost everywhere.

Comment: FWIW, every hot dog vendor and ice cream stand we patronized in Stockholm earlier this year happily accepted credit cards.

Comment: Things have continued to change since this answer was written: many coffee shops and summer "fik" don't accept cash any more. Swish is taking over the role that cash had.

Answer (score 7):

I visited Sweden from the UK three weeks ago. Every shop I went into, even the tiny little cafes and the otherwise fairly haphazard outdoor ice rink, were perfectly happy to accept both my UK VISA debit and my Mastercard credit card.

There are indeed some places that do not accept cash but most still do: those that don't have fairly prominent signs (usually only in Swedish) near the registers to say so.

Comment: the number of cashless places is steadily increasing, but the worst case would be going to an ATM an withdraw some cash

Answer (score 7):

## Visa and Mastercard works fine, chip is preferred

Visa and Mastercard works pretty much everywhere.

Chipped card is the preferred way to go.

Swiping is no longer in use at all.

About a quarter of all machines have enabled RFID (estimate from personal experience).

ATMs will give you Swedish currency from your Visa and Mastercard if you need it, but you rarely do. I as a Swedish citizen cannot even identify the new coins we have since over a year back because I use cash so seldom, less than once per quarter year.